# how much should I pay my graphic designers for clothing?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, client-relations, freelance, pricing

I have 2 graphic designers working for me right now, one a senior level, and the other is at amateur level. WE'RE currently paying per design by a fixed cost and commission. The senior graphic designer has sent me an invoice and the cost would be $110, while the commission fee for each individual sale will be $1. We're just starting new so this seems too much for us, but at the same time we also understand that it could also be a good deal as it's designed by a senior graphic designer. Should I bargain for a little less? The designer is from Paraguay for an insight.

Comment: Ii think it's impossible to answer your question: this is just number that exists in vacuum. 110 could be a lot for 20 minutes of work, could be a little for 10 hours of work. If you can't evaluate the work of the designer yourself I believe you have only two options: to trust them or pay/ask some other designers you trust to make the evaluation

Comment: If the driving factor for sales are the designs.. you should possibly be thankful the price is reasonable. In reality, if the design itself is the selling point, the designer may be right in asking for more than 50% of the revenue generated - since without the design, there would be little or no sales.

Answer (score 1):

Lets think about this for a bit

- Designer asks 110$ commission

  OK so that translates roughly to 1 day of work in most western countries, maybe 2 in non-western. First, there is some tax lets say for simplicity its 10% it probably isn't but lets keep it simple.

  This means designer is taking home 99$. Of this the designer needs to subtract their expenses (Electricity, computer, software, internet etc. which are as much mostly everywhere). Let say 9$ so we get a nice round sum of 90$. Is that much? Well if we would use a worker in US McDonald's as a reference they get something like 9 $ 30 cents lets say for simplicity of calculation 9$ per hour.

  that would mean that at a rate usually considered slave wages the designer could work 10 hours for you. But since they are in Paraguay that kind of salary could be somewhat decent.

  Note that most of this time spent in correspondence with you. If you now ask for even lower price that means 1 hour more work, before anything gets done. So no 110$ sounds like a good deal to me
- while the commission fee for each individual sale will be $1.

  Well your product can not have graphic design then. Many cheap goods don't have any of this stuff on it. Nobody said that selling bulk goods is easy.

  Note that you, yourself need to realistically also make about 9$ per hour. So you still need huge volumes sold to make any money. just writing and reading this answer cost you 9$. So 110$ does not seem like insurmountable amount, or your out of business anyway.